# jupyter is showing callable error in dict function

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter

```
dicts=dict([("first",1), ("second",2)])
dicts
-------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ced152e9bd1a> in <module>
----> 1 dicts=dict([("first",1), ("second",2)])
      2 dicts

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You have ```dict``` as a variable some where in the code

Comment: Check your code as @Sujay mentioned, I am certain you are using dict as a variable somewhere. Since you are using jupyter notebook, check one of the cells.